# How to save a customize plot using ggsave with all customized properties?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggsave

I have a plot and then I changed some by default properties of `ggplot` like `font face, font color, bold` etc. However, when I am opening the plot using command or from `Rstudio's plot` the image contains all my customize property.

However, when I am saving the plot using `ggsave` it is not showing and saving all the customized properties of the image. More specifically my saved image is not showing the properties given in `them()`.

My code is given below

```
plot <- ggplot(plot_df, aes(Region, diff, fill = Region))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  theme_bw()+
  
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black",size=10,face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black",size=10,face="bold")
  )+
  xlab("Region")+
  ylab("Average Region Rainfall (mm)")+
  ggtitle("Average Region Ranfall")
```

Saving code using `ggsave`

```
ggsave("~/My/plot.png", plot = plot+
         theme_bw(base_size = 10, base_family = "Times New Roman"), width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 150, units = "in", device='png')
```

Is there any way to save the original plot using ggsave?

Comment: The issue is that by saving `plot+ theme_bw(base_size = 10, base_family = "Times New Roman")` you are overwriting all customized theme arguments with the defaults from theme_bw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `theme_bw()` with `theme()`. Hopefully, this will work.

```
ggsave("~/My/plot.png", plot = plot+
         theme(), width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 150, units = "in", device='png')
```